# Javascript: Only allow 7 digits for input and automatically add hyphen(-) after only 3rd number

Tags: javascript

I want to restrict the input field in the following manner.

- always 000-0000 format
- auto insert "-" right after having 3 digits don't let user to add -
- don't let a user type more than 7 digits
- do not accept other than integer

**What I have tried**

On keyup event of input field I am calling keyUpValidation method

```
keyUpValidation(event) {
   let value = event.target.value;
   document.getElementById('input').value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, "$1");
   if (value.length == 3) {
    document.getElementById('input').value = value + "-";
   }
},
```

**What does this code do?**

It doesn't allow the user to add anything other than digit/number also insert hyphen (-) after the 3rd digit but as soon as the user inputs the 4th digit the hyphen(-) is getting replaced.

Comment: `fieldValue` is a `const` and it is not a reference to the input field's value. Writing to it won't work. You should write the processed value to `document.getElementById('input').value`

Comment: You are also mixing up the local `value` and `this.value` of your containing class. You write the processed value to `this.value`, but never use `this.value` again. You are using the unprocessed `value` afterwards.

Comment: Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Side note, the value of an input field can change without a key event (e.g. right click and paste from clipboard), make sure to listen for `onChange` event too.

Comment: Nice Catch @RickyMo I have updated the code in question as well but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two inputs. Take this commented example (updated to allow copy-pasting ease):

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper"),
  p1 = document.getElementById("p1"),
  dash = document.getElementById("dash"),
  p2 = document.getElementById("p2");

p1.addEventListener("input", e => {
  // if length is 3
  if (p1.value.length >= 3) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent extra text from being added
    dash.style.visibility = "visible"; // show dash
    p2.removeAttribute("disabled"); // remove disabled
    let remainingValues = p1.value.slice(3); // get next four values
    p1.value = p1.value.substring(0, 3);
    p1.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    p2.value = remainingValues.substring(0, 4); // set value for next element; limit to 4; enhance copy-pasting as users will likely copy-paste
    if (p2.value.length === 4) {
      p2.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
      const userInput = p1.value + p2.value; // done
      done(userInput);
    }
    p2.focus(); // focus
  }
});
p2.addEventListener("input", e => {
  if (p2.value.length >= 4) {
    p2.setAttribute("disabled", "true"); // disable to prevent extra text
    const userInput = p1.value + p2.value; // done
    done(userInput);
  }
});

wrapper.addEventListener("click", e => {
  p1.focus(); // emulate input focus
});
// uncomment to autofocus:
// p1.focus();

function done(val) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

```css
/*some styles to make the wrapper look like an input*/

#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  width: fit-content;
  transition: .2s;
}

#wrapper:focus-within {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

#wrapper,
#wrapper * {
  cursor: text;
}

input[type="number"] {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}


/*remove the step button on numbers*/

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#dash {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#p1 {
  width: 25px;
}

#p2 {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p>Test copy-paste&mdash;copy: 1234567</p>
<!--using a wrapper div to emulate an input-->
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type="number" id="p1" />
  <span id="dash">-</span>
  <input type="number" id="p2" disabled />
</div>
```

Comment: Sir need to do this only in 1 input field

Comment: @HamzaMughal Are you taking a class or something that requires you only use one input or is that your necessity? As you can see, just concatenate input value 1 and value 2 together to get the code. Also, it would be very difficult to do what you requested with one input...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxlength` property in html: [See Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp)

```html
<input type="number" maxlength="7" />
```

Use this Pattern for `separate numbers`

```js
const pattern = new RegExp("(-?[0-9]{3})([0-9]*)");
```

Accept `only integer` type

```js
const pattern = new RegExp("[^0-9]", "ig");
```

Comment: When using `-` set the `maxlength` to **8**

Comment: Can you still visually add the hyphen to the input box if it's set to type "number"?

Comment: @SourceMatters No, Use the text type. handle it by regex so that nothing but numbers and dashes enter